# Get error message out of Sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I want to get exception error message out of the sidekiq job. when I set back_trace option to true it retries my job but I want to exit from job when error raises and get error message.

if I find that process ended successful or fail is enough.

```
def perform(text)
    begin
      fail StandardError, 'Error!' 
    rescue
      fail 'EEE' # I want to get this error when call job
    end
end
# call
NormalJob.perform_async('test')
# I want to get error here after call
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I were you I would try gem [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status). It has several options, which can be helpful in such situations:

You can **retrieve status** of your worker:

```
job_id = MyJob.perform_async(*args)
# :queued, :working, :complete or :failed , nil after expiry (30 minutes)
status = Sidekiq::Status::status(job_id)
Sidekiq::Status::queued?   job_id
Sidekiq::Status::working?  job_id
Sidekiq::Status::complete? job_id
Sidekiq::Status::failed?   job_id
```

Also you have options for `Tracking progress, saving and retrieveing data associated with job`

```
class MyJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker # Important!

  def perform(*args)
    # your code goes here

    # the common idiom to track progress of your task
    total 100 # by default
    at 5, "Almost done"

    # a way to associate data with your job
    store vino: 'veritas'

    # a way of retrieving said data
    # remember that retrieved data is always is String|nil
    vino = retrieve :vino
  end
end

job_id = MyJob.perform_async(*args)
data = Sidekiq::Status::get_all job_id
data # => {status: 'complete', update_time: 1360006573, vino: 'veritas'}
Sidekiq::Status::get     job_id, :vino #=> 'veritas'
Sidekiq::Status::at      job_id #=> 5
Sidekiq::Status::total   job_id #=> 100
Sidekiq::Status::message job_id #=> "Almost done"
Sidekiq::Status::pct_complete job_id #=> 5
```

Another option is to use sidekiq [batches status](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches#status)

This is what batches allow you to do!

```
batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
batch.description = "Batch description (this is optional)"
batch.notify(:email, :to => 'me@example.org')
batch.jobs do
  rows.each { |row| RowWorker.perform_async(row) }
end
puts "Just started Batch #{batch.bid}"

b = Sidekiq::Batch.new(bid) # bid is a method on Sidekiq::Worker that gives access to the Batch ID associated to the job.
b.jobs do
  SomeWorker.perform_async(1)
  sleep 1
  # Uh oh, Sidekiq has finished all outstanding batch jobs
  # and fires the complete message!
  SomeWorker.perform_async(2)
end

status = Sidekiq::Batch::Status.new(bid)
status.total # jobs in the batch => 98
status.failures # failed jobs so far => 5
status.pending # jobs which have not succeeded yet => 17
status.created_at # => 2012-09-04 21:15:05 -0700
status.complete? # if all jobs have executed at least once => false
status.join # blocks until the batch is considered complete, note that some jobs might have failed
status.failure_info # an array of failed jobs
status.data # a hash of data about the batch which can easily be converted to JSON for javascript usage
```

It can be used out of the box

Comment: Ok, i am using sidekiq 3.1 and when I install its gem it raises: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sidekiq": ...

Comment: I am using sidekiq '~> 3.0.2' and this gem is working. I hope it will work soon with 3.1 https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status/pull/30

Comment: I installed sidekiq 3.0.2 and solved the problem. but status is always nil. what is the problem?

Comment: Thank you all. problem solved when use sidekiq-status middleware.